# What is the polite word describing a person who unreasonably says and does things to make a person happy?

Tags: word-choice

Assume a powerful or rich person (like a boss in an office) and assume there is guy who wants to get some benefits from that person. He always does every thing and says every lies to make the powerful guy happy. I know an impolite phrase to describe this person, which has something to do with kissing certain part of the body of the powerful guy. But, I was wondering what is the polite and literal way to call this type of individuals and what is called this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you are only looking for words that are less vulgar than the one you have in mind.

In that case, words such as [*toady*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toady), [*sycophant*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sycophant) or [*flatterer*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatterer) work fine. However, I should point out that these words, while not vulgar, are still derogatory.

[*Complimenter*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complimenter) is the only word I can think of that comes close to your description while not being as derogatory as the ones I've already suggested.

Comment: I think sycophant is the best word to describe such a person politely. In fact the impolite equivalent word appears as a synonym of sycophant in the link you provided.

Answer (score 3):

*Appeaser* is a literal, non-vulgur term for this kind person.

*[appease](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appease)* (verb) - to make (someone) pleased or less angry by giving or saying something desired

In context this can be a polite, but offense term:

> She's a real *appeaser* isn't she.

Or it can be used quite literally:

> Let's *appease* the court by handing over the documentation.

A less formal, and less polite term is *suck-up*

*[suck-up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suck-up)* (noun) - a person who is ingratiating or fawning

It can also be used as a verb.

eg.

> I'm going to *suck-up* to the boss in hope of getting a pay rise.

Comment: I just looked up the word you are suggesting. But it seems "appease" has a positive meaning and it can be used to describe a good action of reducing the intensity of someone's feelings. But I am asking about a word which is has only a negative meaning and describes an action usually done by a low life person.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh - The amusing irony is, I considered adding a note that 'someone is still going to be offended if you call them this'.

Answer (score 0):

*propitiative*

pro·pi·ti·ate  (pr-psh-t)
tr.v. pro·pi·ti·at·ed, pro·pi·ti·at·ing, pro·pi·ti·ates
To conciliate (an offended power); appease: propitiate the gods with a sacrifice.

*con·cil·i·ate*  (kn-sl-t)
v. con·cil·i·at·ed, con·cil·i·at·ing, con·cil·i·ates
v.tr.
1. To overcome the distrust or animosity of; appease.
2. To regain or try to regain (friendship or goodwill) by pleasant behavior.
3. To make or attempt to make compatible; reconcile.
v.intr.
To gain or try to gain someone's friendship or goodwill. See Synonyms at pacify.